# How to access an instance relation using strings in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, abstract

Supose I have a class named `Classroom` and I have another class named `Student`.
From their relationship I can access Student by using `Classroom.students` which returns an array of students.

Now, taking that in consideration, if I assign `'Classroom'` to a variable and call it with `variable.constantize` it will return the Class from where I can query normally.

eg:

```
[1] pry(main)> variable = 'Classroom'
[2] pry(main)> variable.constantize.students
=> [#<Student id: 1, name: 'Foo Smith'>, <Student id: 2, name: 'Bar Obama'>]
```

All of that works for me but I have no idea on how to access students if the key name is also stored as a string. This works if I'm trying to access a `Classroom` field but for relations it seems to be impossible.

eg:

```
[1] pry(main)> variable = 'Classroom'
[2] pry(main)> class_key = 'name'
[3] pry(main)> relation_key = 'students'
[4] pry(main)> variable.constantize.first[class_key]
=> "Happy Classroom"
[5] pry(main)> variable.constantize.first[key]
=> nil
```

There's also another case in which the string is a method from the class.

What I wanted to do *(mock code)*:

```
[1] pry(main)> variable = 'Classroom'
[2] pry(main)> method = 'last'
[3] pry(main)> variable.constantize[method]
=> <#Classroom id: 3, name: 'Dubious Classroom'>
```

Any of those are feasible in Ruby?
Thanks!

Comment: Association methods are called on model instances and not the class itself. `Classroom.first.students` works while `Classroom.students` will give you a NoMethodError. I'm guessing your doing something strange here like assigning an instance of a class to a constant.

Answer (score 4):

Use [Object.public_send](https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/public_send), like this:

```
'Classroom'.constantize.public_send('students').public_send('first')
```

Edit: original answer suggested using `send` instead of `public_send`. The difference is that the former will call even the private methods, so it's less safe to use than the latter.

Comment: Prefer `public_send` over `send`

Comment: Oh, yes! Definitely that's much better option. Thank you.

Comment: It's also worth noting that it's absolutely critical that these two string arguments are not arbitrary user parameters and that they **must be whitelisted**. Failing to do this could expose you to huge security risks because it allows fairly arbitrary method calls in your application.